# More Synonymous Tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tag-synonym-request

I think there are a couple more synonymous tags that need dealing with?  We currently have synth and synthesizer which I see as being the same?  There is then tags for synthesis and granular-synthesis which I think could be combined?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think synthesis and granular synthesis should be combined. Granular synthesis is a form of synthesis. Regarding synthesizer vs synth I agree, remove synth would be my the best option in my opinion.

Comment: Do we really want a separate tag for every different type of synthesis: Additive, Subtractive, FM, Wavetable, Granular, etc. IMO one tag called Synthesis or synthesis_techniques could cover all of these.  Interested to know what others think though.

Comment: Sorry, I think you're right. Although it could make searching a bot easier, however people could still just search for FM or Wavetable. I was responding to quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I think [synth](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synth) and [synthesizer](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthesizer) are certainly referring to the same thing, and I've proposed a synonym. owever, I'm not sure if [synthesis](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthesis) (meaning making sounds via synthesis) and [synthesizer](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthesizer) (the instrument) are necessarily appropriate on the same questions, so I haven't touched those.

I *definitely* think that the different categories of synthesis (additive, subtractive, granular, frequency modulation, etc) do not need their own tags, and will work just fine within one catch-all [synthesis](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthesis) tag. Currently there are just over 100 questions with a tag contaning the string `synth` so I don't think being any more specific with such tags is going to help much.

Other opinions?

Comment: IMO Synthesis would cover the principles of synthesis techniques, whereas Synthesizer would allow you to cover the implementation. As ever, just my thoughts.

Comment: Agreed synth, synthesizer (and synthesiser) should be synonyms

Answer (score 2):

I think car/cars and vehicle/vehicles can be combined: even though one is a subset of the other, the majority of the questions and answers will apply to the broader category and will be of interest to people looking for information about cars or any other corner of the category.